# Find the Average marks for each student

Tags: c++, for-loop

There are 5 Students and 3 subjects.My problem is that when  the Average marks for each student are being calculated , the average marks  for the previous student is being added to the average marks calculated just after!
Anyone could figure out what's wrong or what's missing in the piece of code please! Thank you :)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i,j;
    double ave,scores,total=0.0;

    for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Marks for Student"<<j<<":"<<endl;
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            cout<<" subject"<<i<<":";
            cin>>scores;
            total+=scores;
        }
        ave=total/3;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped you by clicking the big check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not "zeroing out" your total counter when moving on to the next average computation. This is a trivial problem that you would be able to solve if stepping through the code line by line.

**If you don't practice this now, it'll be incredibly difficult to solve more complex problems. Next question you ask, please post what you have tried.**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int i,j;
double ave,scores,total=0.0;

 for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
     {
      cout<<"Marks for Student"<<j<<":"<<endl;
         for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
               cout<<" subject"<<i<<":";
                cin>>scores;
                total+=scores;
            }
       ave=total/3;

       // Changes here
       cout<<"average:" << ave << endl; // print it here
       ave=0; // zero it out

       cout<<endl;
     }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `total` to `0` for every student in the for loop. Something like:

```
for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
     {
      cout<<"Marks for Student"<<j<<":"<<endl;
      total = 0.0;
         for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
            {
               cout<<" subject"<<i<<":";
                cin>>scores;
                total+=scores;
            }
       ave=total/3;
       cout<<endl;
     }
```